# SSL port 443 conflict, how to make iis7.5 not think another process is running?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ssl, iis-7.5

I am running a asp.net mvc2 application on iis7.5 using a SSL certificate for port 443.

but as soon as I add port 443 to the Bindings (on "Site Bindings") it wont browse to the site through the HTTPS scheme complainng of another process working.

I have tried renaming port 80 to 8080 to no avail.

Hope someone can help.

All the best

Paul

*Please note this addition it may save time for you:

ADDED NOTE: THE ANSWER TO THIS WAS TO TURN OFF SKYPE AS IT HAD CONTROL OF PORT 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kinda sounds like you already have a site using port 443.  SSL can't run on a shared IP; the certificate needs to be verified even before the server knows which site's cert to use.

Make sure other sites (especially the default one) aren't bound to the site's address and port.

Comment: thanks, that sounds like a plan.

Can you recommend the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: The easiest way i can think of is to unbind your site from port 443, go to it via HTTPS (ignoring any certificate errors), and see what pops up.

Comment: Thanks you are right, it was not another site, rather SKYPE running in the background.